# How to pass a default value for a field in 'insert' form?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

How to pass a default value for a field in 'insert' form?

I'm using Meteor's packages: Autoform, Collections2, and Simple-Schema.

My process is:

1. A User selects some value in a list on a page, then
2. The 'insert' from opens, and I want that one field to be initialized with the value the user chose on a previous step.

Can't figure out how to pass a parameter withing URL (or any other way).
The problem is how to initialize form with the value.

Suppose I have an URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/activity/new/Sport
```

===============
router.js:

```
...
Router.map(function () {
    ...
    this.route('newActivity', {
        path: '/activity/new/:tag',
        data: function() {
            Session.set('tag', this.params.tag);
            return null;
        }
    });
    ...
```

===============
models/activity.js

```
...
Activities = new Meteor.Collection("activities", {
    schema: {
        title: {
            type: String,
            label: 'название'
        },
        ...
        tag: {
            type: String,
            label: 'тэг'
        }
    }
});
```

================
templates/avtibity.js

```
...
Template.newActivity.helpers({
    defaultTag: function() {
        return Session.get('tag');
    }
});
...
```

================
templates/activity.html

```
...
<template name="newActivity">
    <h1>Create new Activity!</h1>
    {{#autoForm collection="Activities" id="insertActivityForm" type="insert"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="title"}}
        ...
        {{> afQuickField name="tag" value="   ??????    "}} // ? {{defaultTag}}
        ho ho ho {{defaultTag}}
    {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Eric Dobbertin:

1. You could set value equal to a helper that returns the desired value ({{> afQuickField name="tag" value=valueHelper}})
2. List item You could set doc to an object that has the value set to what you want. Just like you would for an update form.

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/210

Comment: You should probably specify in the original post and topic title that you're using the Autoform, Collections2, and Simple-Schema packages.

Comment: How would I access the value of the valueHelper in my schema?